# question mark after variable/object name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to ruby on rails. Thanks for your patience in advance.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= @pin.image_url if @pin.image? %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
</div>
```

1. What does `@pin.image?`  do?
   There is not image? method in my controller. I'm guessing it's one of the helper functions provided by rails for every controller? Is that right?
2. What is f ?

here is my model for pin

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged    
    belongs_to :board
end
```

and its schema

```
class CreatePins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :image
      t.integer :board_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class AddImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :pins, :image, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: It isn't your model for `pin`, it's only your db schema for `pins` table. The model is probably located in `app/models/pin.rb` file.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is not image? method in my controller.

You don't call this method on your controller, but on your object assigned to `@pin` variable, which is probably your `Pin` model. And your model does have `image?` method.

> What is f ?

It's the [form builder object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html), passed into `form_for` block.

Comment: My pin model does not have image? method.

Comment: @MWL yes, it does. It's generated automatically by `ActiveRecord` on the basis of your db schema. Since `pins` table has `image` column, `image`, `image=` and `image?` methods are generated automatically, at least in Rails 4.1.6 (I think in Rails 3 generation of `?` method was limited to boolean columns, but I'm not sure).

Comment: `@pin.image?` is a shortcut for `@pin.attribute_present?(:image)`. According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attribute_present-3F), it returns `true` if the attribute is neither `nil` nor `empty?`.

Comment: @Stefan thanks. I was wondering if `@pin.image?` is an equivalent to `!!@pin.image` or to `@pin.image.present?`.